# Функция для изменения окончания слов в зависимости от числа

Tags: access, база-данных

функция, которая будет изменять окончание слов в зависимости от числа.
Нужно вывести в отчет разное количество часов [например: 1944 часа, 216 часов, 391 часи т.д.]. `Access 2007`. В отчете числовое поле и текстовое поле.

Comment: все вопрос решен спасибо

Comment: [Повтор вопроса](http://hashcode.ru/questions/89458/)

Answer (score 2):

В качестве отправной точки можете посмотреть на:

- http://msa.polarcom.ru/st/s0000120.htm
- http://msa.polarcom.ru/st/s0000041.htm